# ¿Cómo hacer un nuevo release en GitHub y trabajar en diferentes versiones?

Tags: git, github

Tengo un ***proyecto en GitHub*** al cual quiero hacerle cambios pero mantenerlos tambien en su version anterior(es un proyecto de react ahora cambiare algunas cosas para que sea con Redux quiero mantenerlo tambien sin Redux)..  buscando un poco en GitHub veo que se hace a través de releases.

Ya la creé; pero no se como cambiar entre releases, es decir, si quiero modificar mi version **1.0 sin redux** o si luego quiero moverme y cambiar mi version **2.0 con redux**...

¿Tendre que hacer un nuevo repositorio?

Comment: haz probado creandote ramas?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con release desde la UI de github o utilizar los TAGS

Comment: ya hice una release desde la UI actualmente solo uso la rama master y no se como puedo usar las ramas para trabajar con una u otra release

Comment: git checkout nombreDeLaRamav1 git checkout nombreDeLaRamav2 así te puedes ir moviendo entre las ramas sin problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te sugiero que utilices `tags`:

> Como muchos VCSs, Git tiene la habilidad de etiquetar (tag) puntos específicos en la historia como importantes.

Para crear un nuevo `tag` sobre el `commit` actual debes usar el siguiente comando:

```
git tag v1.0.0
```

Y para publicarlo en, por ejemplo, GitHub debes usar el siguiente comando:

```
git push origin master --tags
```

Puedes conocer más sobre las [etiquetas en la documentación oficial](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Creando-etiquetas).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta @Roxgüel Creo q los tags es lo mas parecido a lo que quiero hacer el problema es q los push los sigo haciendo a mi proyecto... digamos que mi https://github.com/usuario/proyecto ->(version 1.0) cuando hago git tag v2.0 bien me hizo un nuevo release pero este release como lo edito luego y dejo mi version 1.0 sin cambios.. yo trabajo desde dos ordenadores si lo hago asi pudira descargar los zip y trabajar luego tendria q hacer un nuevo tag ej: 2.1 con los cambios para no modificar mi version 1.0..

Comment: lo que puedo hacer lo inverso de lo que pensaba un nuevo  tag con la version 1.0 seguir avanzando en mi repositorio que seria mi version 2.0 y para luego editar mi version 1.0 tendria q descargarla y hacer un nuevo tag 1.1 con las ediciones

Answer (score 3):

puedes intentar creando ramas para trabajar en diferentes versiones

sigue los siguientes pasos

Crea y te cambia a la rama creada

> git checkout -b nombrerama

si requieres regresar a la rama master o cambiarte a otra

> git checkout master

para fusionar ejemplo a la rama master, primero te posicionas a la rama master y realizas el merge a la rama a ser fusionada

> git checkout master
>
> git merge nombrerama

una ves fusionada puedes eliminar la rama si así lo requieres

> git branch -d nombrerama

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crearte ramas, asi puedes trabajar con comandos.

```
git branch "release1"
git branch             // lista todas las ramas que tienes     
          master
          release1
git checkout release1  // para cambiar a la rama release
git merge master       // para unir los cambios del master en tu rama release1
git push origin release1
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @x-rw pero lo que eh visto de las ramas es que te hace una version que luego tienes que hacer un merge a tu respositorio original cambiandolo

Comment: @IsraelGonzález una rama puede vivir hasta que la mergeas, pero si no mergeas al master entonces seguira viva